# Forms Auth, SharePoint Group, Form Group, Workflow Email notification

Tags: 2007, workflow, forms-authentication

We have a publishing site using MOSS2007 that is using a Forms authentication and our own Membership and Role Provider

We want to have a workflow that sends emails to the Approvers SharePoint group when content is created in a list.

The problem we have is that we have to add our users directly to the SharePoint 'Approvers' Group for the email's to be sent.

What we want to be able to do is add the custom Role to the SharePoint group, and have any users who are granted that role in our custom role admin system to be emailed.

SharePoint doesn't seem to be doing this

SharePoint Group > Custom Group > CustomUser.email address traversal

Instead, it only seems to manage looking up.

SharePoint Group > CustomUser.emailAddress

Answer (score 1):

I take it this custom role / group resides within your custom membership and role provider. I'm a little rusty on this but SharePoint gets data like email addresses from its own profile store. You'll need to tell SharePoint where to get these email addresses from.

Comment: We have, we think. Wharepoint will resolve the email address if the custom user is added to the group directly, but not if the custom group is added, it just isn't making that leap from looking up the group members and then their email addresses.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. I think I've observed this problem too, using an AD membership provider: SharePoint doesn't want to recurse through the security group structure to find email addresses. It will only get email addresses of immediate members.